# Is $f(x)\exp(-x^2)$ summable if $f$ is square summable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$; i.e.
$$
\int_{- \infty}^\infty \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx < \infty.
$$
Can we from this infer that
$$
\int_{- \infty}^\infty \vert f(x)\vert e^{-x^2} \, dx < \infty\text{ ?}
$$
Intuitively this is clear since $\exp(-x^2)$ decays at least as good as $f$, however how to prove it? Can we represent $f$ as some worst case function when it comes to decay, and prove it from there? For instance, can we say that there exists a $\Delta$ such that $e^{-x^2} \leq \vert f(x) \vert$ for $x \geq \Delta$? If we can then we would be done:
$$
\int_{- \infty}^\infty \vert f(x) \vert e^{-x^2} dx \leq \int_{\vert x \vert \leq \Delta} \vert f(x) \vert e^{- x^2} dx + \int_{\vert x \vert \geq \Delta} \vert f(x) \vert^2 \, dx < \infty.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential fact is not something about $e^{-x^2}$ decaying fast, but is not unrelated to that either.  The essential fact is this:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx < \infty.
$$

The point is that if $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $L^2(X)\subseteq L^1(X)$.  So let $X=\mathbb R$ and let $\mu$ be this measure:
$$
e^{-x^2}\,dx.
$$

Comment: This viewpoint was new to me, thanks! Just out of curiosity, would my approach work even though it is not very elegant?

Comment: @user128779 : I don't know whether something like that can work.  I don't know what a "worst case" would be like. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

**Big Hint :**

By Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$\int|f(x)e^{-x^2}| \, dx\leq \sqrt{\int|f(x)|^2 \, dx}\sqrt{\int e^{-2x^2} \, dx}.$$